# How to fix 'Expected the return value to be a 31-bit integer' error react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a counter for experienced hooks with context api everything works but I have a warning :

> *Warning: calculateChangedBits: Expected the return value to be a 31-bit integer. Instead received: undefined*

#### my context

```
export const CountCtx = createContext(0, () => {});

function CountContext() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="cp1">
      <CountCtx.Provider value={[count, setCount]}>
        <p>Component where i created the context 'CountCtx'<br/>Counter is {count}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
        <ComponentA/>
      </CountCtx.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Component A

```
function ComponentA() {
  const [count, setCount] = useContext(CountCtx);

  return (
    <div className="cp2">
      <p><b>Component A</b><br/>Counter is {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</button>
      <ComponentB/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Component B

```js
function ComponentB() {
  const [count, setCount] = useContext(CountCtx);

  return (
    <div className="cp3">
      <p><b>Component B</b><br/>Counter is {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count -1)}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks a lot i dont understand this warning :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second parameter in `createContext` is [undocumented `calculateChangedBits` callback function](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.8.6/packages/react/src/ReactContext.js#L19).

Since invalid callback was provided, this prevents the context from working:

```
export const CountCtx = createContext(0, () => {});
```

It should be:

```
export const CountCtx = createContext(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

createContext expects a return value when using a function as an argument. The function that you used does not have a return value. So, instead of

```
export const CountCtx = createContext(0, () => {});
```

it should be

```
export const CountCtx = createContext(0, () => {return 1}); or export const CountCtx = createContext(0, () => 1);
```